# How to prevent InvalidOperationException when using System.Drawing.Graphics?

Tags: .net, graphics, concurrency, system.drawing, invalidoperationexception

I am using the `System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLines(Pen pen, PointF[] points)` method in a multithreaded application, but the `System.Drawing.Graphics` isn't shared between threads.

Why it keeps throwing the `System.InvalidOperationException: The object is currently in use elsewhere` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was: I was using the same System.Drawing.Pen instance for all threads. I had to clone it for every thread in order to solve the problem.

```
var pens = new Pen[0];
lock (this._pens)
{
    pens = (Pen[])this._pens.Select(a => (Pen) a.Clone()).ToArray();
}
```

Even the lock is essential in order to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: don't do that. Only access the GUI on the GUI thread.

Comment: It can happen in a GUI project. Please keep your answer so other users can benefit for it.